# Moving from an ATL COM dll to a C++/CLI dll wrapper.

Tags: c++-cli, wrapper, atl, com-object

I'm working to create a C++/CLI dll from an ATL COM object dll.  Is this type of move possible, and what would need to be done to migrate the classes from the ATL com object to the C++/CLI dll wrapper.

Comment: They have nothing in common, not even the language is the same :)

Comment: If you have an ATL COM object, why don't you use it in the .NET world?